# NodeJS: Why is email undefined during user registration?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing an API using NodeJS with the functionality of user registration and login. When a user register, I get

> "Error: WHERE parameter "email" has invalid "undefined" value" this
>   error."

I have checked similar question and answer here and tried every one of them, but none has worked for me.

**app.js file**

````
```
//use path module
const path = require('path');
//use express module
const express = require('express');
//use ejs view engine
const ejs = require('ejs');
//use bodyParser middleware
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//use mysql database
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();

//Setting port number
const port = process.env.PORT || 619;

const mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'home_automation_db'
});



app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.stuff = {
      url   : req.originalUrl
  }
  next();
});


//connecting to database
mysqlConnection.connect((err) =>{
    if(!err)
    console.log('DB connection successful');
    else
    console.log('connection failed \n Error: '+JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
});

var Users = require('./controllers/lightController');

app.use('/users', Users);

//server listening
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server is running at port '+port);
});
````

**lightcontroller.js**

````
```var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
var generator = require('generate-password');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const cors= require('cors')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const express =require('express')
const users = express.Router();

const User = require('../models/User');

users.use(cors());
process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'secret';
```

```
// Login controller
users.post('/register', function (req, res) {
    const userData = {
        user_name: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        location: req.body.location,
        house_number: req.body.house_number
    }
    User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: req.body.email
        }
    }).then(user => {
        if (!user) {
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
                userData.password = hash
                User.create(userData).then(user => {
                    res.json({ status: user.email + "registered" })
                }).catch(err => {
                    res.send('error: ' + err)
                })
            })
        } else {
            res.json({ error: "user already exist." })
        }
    }).catch(err => {
            res.send('error: '+err)
        })
});
```
````

**User model**

```
 const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
    const db = require("../database/db")

    module.exports = db.sequelize.define(
        'user_tb',
        {
            user_id: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            },
            user_name: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            email: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            password: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            location: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            house_number: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            }  
        },
        {
            timestamps: false,
            freezeTableName: true
        }
    )
```

Comment: can you also post the client code? your serverside seems to be ok, i guess that email value is sent as `undefined`

Comment: Have you done some basic debugging yet? Like `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: i am checking from Postman.@messerbill

Comment: so what does it print when you follow @ChrisG 's advise?

Comment: I am getting the error as mentioned from the question i posted. It is displaying the catch part of User.create().

Comment: The `catch` for `User.findOne` does the exact same thing, and the error message points to the find query failing, not the insert one. Again, what does it say in your node console when you check the actual post parameters?

Answer (score 0):

As @messerbill said the most probable cause is the sending of data as `undefined`

Try adding config after post data to your post request on the client side so it sets proper content-type:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:9000/api/login', {
    email: this.state.email,
    password: this.state.password,
}, {
    'content-type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded'
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    if(res.status) {
        console.log('User is logged in');
    }
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```